# Окаймлен летучей пеной, днем и ночью дышит мол

Tags: пунктуация, определения

> Окаймлен летучей пеной, днем и ночью дышит мол.

Почему обособляется определение *окаймлен летучей пеной*？ 
Опр. стоит перед определяемым словом, добавочного значения не имеет, личных местоимений и имен собственных нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Окаймлен летучей пеной,** днем и ночью дышит **мол**.

Оборот находится на расстоянии от определяемого слова, в этом случае он обособляется в обязательном порядке.

Comment: вот, что я пропустила. Спасибо!

Comment: Если определяемое слово стояло бы сразу после оборота, запятая здесь ставилась бы -- даже при полной форме причастия. *Окаймленный летучей пеной, мол дышит днем и ночью*.  Обстоятельственное значение. А уж при краткой форме тем паче.

Answer (score 2):

**Окаймлен летучей пеной, днем и ночью дышит мол.**

> § 52. Всегда выделяются запятыми определения, выраженные краткими прилагательными или страдательными причастиями. Они могут занимать любое положение по отношению к определяемому слову: В привычный час пробуждена, вставала при свечах она (П.); Овеян вещею дремотой, полураздетый лес грустит (Тютч.); Опять мне блеснула, окована сном, хрустальная чаша во мраке ночном (Забол.); Колеблется воздух, прозрачен и чист, в сияющих звездах колеблется лист (Забол.); Тут зверь появился, высок и космат, и так же, как многие прочие звери, узнав человека, отпрянул назад (Забол.). ([Знаки препинания при обособленных согласованных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=135))